# how to conditionally show/hide link in DetailsView ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview

I'm new to ASP.NET, and I'm trying to figure out how to only show a chunk of code in the .aspx file if a value is not null or whitespace.  Here's what I have, within a `DetailsView`:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phone">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtPhone" Text='<%# Bind("Phone") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a href="tel:<%# Eval("Phone") %>">
            <i class="icon-phone"></i>
            <%# Eval("Phone") %>
        </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I want to conditionally hide the whole `a` tag if `Eval("Phone")` is null or whitespace.  I would prefer to do this all in the markup, as opposed to doing something in the code-behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11041649/38743) pointed me in the right direction:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='tel:<%# Eval("Phone") %>'
        Visible='<%# !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Eval("Phone").ToString()) %>'>
    <i class="icon-phone"></i>
    <%# Eval("Phone") %>
</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: Nice.  Glad I could help, even if my exact code didn't quite work for you.

Answer (score 0):

First, change it to an ASP:Hyperlink control.  The html A tag doesn't have a nive convenient Visible property like the ASP:Hyperlink control does.

Then you can set the visibility declaratively.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="Server" NavigateUrl='tel:<%# Eval("Phone") %>' Text='<%# Bind("Phone") %>' Visible = '<%= DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem("phone").ToString().Trim() == "" %>' />
```

Comment: What should `Container` be?  Is that some existing property that should exist, or should I replace that with something else?  The `ID` of my `DetailsView` is `dvOrg`, but trying to do `dvOrg.DataItem("Phone")` has an error "Method, delegate or event is expected".

Comment: Container.DataItem is just there as long as you're within a databound control like a Repeater, FormView, DetailsView, etc.  Documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe.aspx

Comment: `Container` didn't seem to exist, VS wanted to import some `Container` class from `System.ComponentModel` into the .aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you can't do the conditional if within an eval statement. Instead, just wrap the simple eval with the function but To handle this situation i usually add a method called NullHandler(). Consider the function below.

```
protected string NullHandler()(object gridViewObject)
   {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(gridViewObject, DBNull.Value))
      {
            return "Empty";
       }
        else
       {
            return gridViewObject.ToString();
      }
    }
```

then you can put like below

```
<asp:Label ID=”phoneLbl” runat=”server” Text=’<%# NullHandler(Eval(“Phone”)) %>’>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: I am talking with reference to Eval instead of DataBinder.Eval()